# How to store sum's result into an identifier which can be used within query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *,


SUM(

    b1.bit_sum_excl * b1.bit_quantity - 
    if(b1.bit_deduction_percentage = 1, (b1.bit_deduction / 100)*(b1.bit_sum_excl * b1.bit_quantity), b1.bit_deduction)

)  as _total_unconverted,

/*************** _total_unconverted * 0.15 as some_val; ****************/


FROM `bill_items` b1

LEFT JOIN clients_packing_list ON (b1.bit_cli_pack_list_id = clients_packing_list.cli_pack_list_id)


WHERE b1.bit_cli_bill_id = 1 OR b1.bit_cli_bill_id = 0
```

I'd like to be able to add an expression

```
_total_unconverted * 0.15 as _converted
```

into the select.

Currently it complains that it's not a column.

Is there  a way to do this, or must I copy paste the SUM code and add the multiplier?

Comment: wrap up what you have in another select. Then just select your columns + the new calculated column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [user defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) with MySQL in query.

```
SELECT *,
(@total:=SUM(
    b1.bit_sum_excl * b1.bit_quantity - 
    if(b1.bit_deduction_percentage = 1, (b1.bit_deduction / 100)*(b1.bit_sum_excl * b1.bit_quantity), b1.bit_deduction)
))  as _total_unconverted,
(@total * 0.15) as _converted,
FROM `bill_items` b1
LEFT JOIN clients_packing_list ON (b1.bit_cli_pack_list_id = clients_packing_list.cli_pack_list_id)
WHERE b1.bit_cli_bill_id = 1 OR b1.bit_cli_bill_id = 0
```

**Edit :** However, this does not guarantee that the value will be assigned in the correct order. In order to implement it properly, see this small example :

```
SELECT @min_price:=MIN(price),@max_price:=MAX(price) FROM shop;
SELECT * FROM shop WHERE price=@min_price OR price=@max_price;
```

Which is a paste from [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-user-variables.html).

Basically, you assign the values first, then re-select according to the values to make sure they were assigned properly.

Comment: Any idea why _converted might be NULL for me?

Comment: Be careful with user defined variables, MySQL does *not* guarantee that user defined variables will be evaluated in the sequence you expect. The MySQL Reference Manual says "**the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.**"  [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html)

Comment: Well, I guess it doesn't work for me. I get NULL, while @total is a numeric value. I can't accept your answer if behaviour isn't defined.

Comment: @Tool: likely the expression `@total * 0.15` is being evaluated before `@total` is being assigned a value. The value of the user defined variable is retained in the session, so a second execution of the same statement will give a different result. It's always a good idea to *initialize* user-defined variables *before* they are used, either a separate `SET` statement, or in an inline view guaranteed to be evaluated before the variables are used. Checking for a `NULL` value with an `if` doesn't do anything to address the real problem.

Comment: @Tool If you set the variable before the current select, you can access the total after and will be sure it won't be null. See edit, I pasted the example given from documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to reference the column alias `_total_unconverted` in the `SELECT` list of the query that returns that column.

You could wrap the query in a set of parens and reference it as an inline view, and the column alias would be available in the outer query.

In this example, the inner query returns a column `foo`, and that column name can be referenced in the outer query:

```
SELECT v.foo
     , v.foo * 0.15 AS bar
  FROM ( SELECT SUM(col) AS foo FROM mytable ) v
```

But it's not possible to reference `foo` in the SELECT list of the inner query. (MySQL does allow the column alias to be referenced in an `ORDER BY` clause and a `HAVING` clause.)

To avoid the overhead of an inline view, you'd need to repeat the expression.

```
SELECT *
     , SUM(b1.bit_sum_excl * b1.bit_quantity -
         IF(b1.bit_deduction_percentage = 1
           ,(b1.bit_deduction / 100)*(b1.bit_sum_excl * b1.bit_quantity)
           , b1.bit_deduction
         )
       ) AS _total_unconverted
     , SUM(b1.bit_sum_excl * b1.bit_quantity -
         IF(b1.bit_deduction_percentage = 1
           ,(b1.bit_deduction / 100)*(b1.bit_sum_excl * b1.bit_quantity)
           , b1.bit_deduction
         )
       ) * 0.15 AS some_val
  FROM `bill_items` b1
  LEFT
  JOIN clients_packing_list
    ON b1.bit_cli_pack_list_id = clients_packing_list.cli_pack_list_id
 WHERE b1.bit_cli_bill_id IN (0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *,SOURCEQUERY._total_unconverted * 0.15 as some_val FROM
(
SELECT 
SUM(
    b1.bit_sum_excl * b1.bit_quantity - 
    if(b1.bit_deduction_percentage = 1, (b1.bit_deduction / 100)*(b1.bit_sum_excl * b1.bit_quantity), b1.bit_deduction)
)  as _total_unconverted
FROM bill_items AS b1
LEFT JOIN clients_packing_list ON (b1.bit_cli_pack_list_id = clients_packing_list.cli_pack_list_id)
WHERE b1.bit_cli_bill_id = 1 OR b1.bit_cli_bill_id = 0
) AS SOURCEQUERY
```